# How to position a Textbox with Tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

I'm learning Tkinter for GUI. I write the following simple code, I can't change the location of the Textbox even if I try different values in the grid. Whatever value I write, the Textbox **always comes at the left up corner**.

```
from tkinter import *

startingWindow = Tk()
startingWindow.title("Hello")
startingWindow.geometry("400x300")
myEntry = Entry(startingWindow, width=10)
myEntry.grid(column=15, row=15)

startingWindow.mainloop()
```

Instead, I get the following output.

[image]

Note: I'm using Python 3.6 under Windows 7

Comment: All columns 0 to 14 and rows 0 to 14 are empty and therefore all have a width/height of 0. Why do you want a single widget to be placed at a specific position? Usually it's more useful to not look at every widget individually, but rather look at them in your complete layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `place` instead of `grid` like this:

```
from tkinter import *

startingWindow = Tk()
startingWindow.title("Hello")
startingWindow.geometry("400x300")
myEntry = Entry(startingWindow, width=10)
myEntry.place(x=15,y=15) # here

startingWindow.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked :)
But may I ask why grid is not working. I mean all tutorials use grid.

Comment: @AhmedWas In grid method , which row and column to place them. You don’t have to specify the size of the grid. refer http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm

Comment: Happy coding !!